# p:datatable inside p:dialog stretch the dialog to full width of browser

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have upgraded my primefaces application from primefaces version 3.3 to 6.0 (latest). Most of the components and pages are working fine except the pages where p:datatable is shown inside p:dialog. It stretches the dialog to the full width of the browser. If I resize the browser all the columns stacked on each other. What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: What is the behavior you want to happen? Do you want the p:dialog to be a set width or be responsive to the width of the page?

Comment: @TonyScialo: I want this dialog to be responsive to the width of the page. So, when I open the web page in the mobile or tablet it should resize it accordingly.

Comment: did either of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width attribute of the primefaces dialog to a specific value like below:

```
 <p:dialog id="myDlg" widgetVar="myDialog" modal="true" width="1000" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" header="Header" closeOnEscape="true">

  //your table here

 </p:dialog>
```

If in the dialog you also have a form the you can put the entries of the form on a gridPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of PrimeFaces has a "responsive" dialog attribute. So your dialog code should be something like this:

```
<p:dialog> id = "someDialog" widgetVar = "someDialog" modal = "true" responsive = "true">
    //dialog code
</p:dialog>
```

It was put into version 6.0 https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/327